# Why won't jasmine run tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd

I'm just getting started learning jasmine to test JavaScript and for the life of me I can't figure out why Jasmine will run my boolean test but not my math functions test(s). Note, I am using a index.html to run tests, I don't have a specrunner.html, though I do have the jasmine dependencies. This answer has to be simple. I'm clearly missing something.

Jasmine results-
Ran 1 of 2 specs - run all
1 spec, 0 failures, randomized with seed 86651

```
function getOpposite(bool) {
            return !bool; 
        }

        function add(x, y) {
            return x + y;
        }

        describe('math function, addition', () => {
            it('return sum of 2 numbers', () => { //this does not work

                const num1 = 2;
                const num2 = 3;

                const result = add(num1, num2);

                expect(result).toBe(5);
            })
        });

        describe('boolean test', () => {
            it('expect value of true', () => { // this works
               
                let bool = false;

                
                const result = getOpposite(bool);

              
                expect(result).toBe(true);
            })
        });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yszLr7bx/  Seems to work fine

Comment: @Taplar Thanks.. I wonder if my JS dependencies are wrong?

Comment: Not sure.  The fact that you say one of them executes and the other does not is the weird part.